# Uneven load in CPU cores

Tags: kubuntu, cpu, system

I am using intel-5200u processor. When I turn on virtualization my 2 cores always stays at 100% and when I turn it off one core always remains 100%. Why load is not distributed to other cores? And how can I fix this as it is making my system hot...

Comment: I suspect you need to look at what is running to cause the increased load, and likely you'll find it is something that only runs on one thread.

Comment: I changed to Fedora and it seems to be fixed!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be solved after I switched to Fedora 34..!!